# VSCode and Pylance not running module matplotlib appropriately

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, pylance

I need to use the external module, matplotlib. I installed it using the command prompt with the line `pip install matplotlib`. I then added `./source` to the `"python.analysis.extraPaths"` section of the settings.json file in the VSCode workbench. Now, only half of my code runs. It will only show the result of the first `plt.plot(x,y)` (please see code below) and the rest of the code won't run. But if comment that line out, then I get the following result in my terminal (please see image) [terminal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYT6M.png). If I try to run the code without debugging (ctrl + F5), i get the following result in terminal: `C:\Users\Alejandro_DIYPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: No module named matplotlib.__main__; 'matplotlib' is a package and cannot be directly executed`.
Has anybody gone through the same thing or has had a similar experience that can help me out?
Thank you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [1500, 1200, 1100, 1800]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
#^this shows the x and y plot for each list respectively.
#The lists have to be numeric. but a leyend can be assigned to the values
legend = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]
plt.xticks(x, legend)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your question is totally unrelated to the title of your question.  You should change the title.

Comment: The error in your image seems obvious.  You are plotting 4 points, but you have provided 12 labels.  How did you expect that to work?

Comment: @TimRoberts, Changed the title. Hope that its better. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the title is still technically wrong, because this is a user error, as I described above.